# how to add validation to control using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i want to add validation to control below: can any one show me to do it with jquery or javascript

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>UserName: <span>*</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="userName" value=""  size="40">                
                         </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td>Display Name: <span>*</span></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""  size="40" >
                        </td>
                    </tr>


             </tbody>
             </table>
```

Comment: can you use [jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin

Comment: can you be a bit more specific please? what kind of validation do you need?

Comment: As stated, describe more about what you want and show an attempt at doing this yourself.  We're not here to write your code for you... we're here to help you when you get stuck.

Comment: Thank yous all i could solve the problem i use jquery.validationEngine.js to solve the problem

Comment: Thank for the answer i problem now solved because i import the wrong library.

Answer (score 2):

Using [jquery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate):

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="Name is too long. Max length is 40 chars" data-val-length-max="40" name="name" type="text" value="">
```

JS:

```
$(".yourTableSelector").validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='userName']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
       alert('This field cannot be empty');
    }
});

$("input[name='name']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
       alert('This field cannot be empty');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) as well. Set ID of those two inputs and then in JavaScript:

```
$.post("validation.php", { username: $("#usernameInputID").val(), displayName: $("#displayNameInputID").val() }).done(function(data) {
    //Some code (if invalid, fox example set border to red etc...)
});
```

In validation.php you can check if received string are empty, if username is unique etc and depending on this return some value (with simple echo), which you can use in JavaScript to decide, if input is correct or not... You can check every input single and then you can alert user than only some field is not filled correctly.